# Start enumerating an item in the same line after a exercise number

Tags: equations, align, enumerate

(I´m sorry my English mistakes)
I have been using a good command for enumerate exercises. It was suggest here for someone (thanks again).

Is it possible to use this command to enumerate exercises together with the \begin{enumerate][??] command´s but that the item starts immediately after the enumeration in the same line? Because the item stars in another line.

For example, I would like this:

1. (a)

   (b)

   (c)

Thank you.

Here is my Latex commands

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}%{\article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}


\newcounter{theeq} \setcounter{theeq}{0}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\noindent%
    \refstepcounter{theeq}\textbf{\arabic{theeq}} {\hspace{-0.1cm{{.}}}} }
\newcommand{\eqz}{{\setcounter{eq}{1}} {{\arabic{eq}}} \refstepcounter{eq}\hspace{-0.1cm{{.}}}}

\begin{document}


\eq. \begin{enumerate}[$(a)$]
    \item Prove that...
    \item Next ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: take a look to the [exam](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hereis a solution which plays with `leftmargin=`  and `before=` keys:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}%
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amscd, bezier}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{theeq} \setcounter{theeq}{0}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\noindent%
    \refstepcounter{theeq}\textbf{\arabic{theeq}} {\hspace{-0.1cm{{.}}}} }
\newcommand{\eqz}{{\setcounter{eq}{1}} {{\arabic{eq}}} \refstepcounter{eq}\hspace{-0.1cm{{.}}}}

\begin{document}

\eq. \begin{enumerate}[$(a)$, leftmargin=3.2em, before=\vspace*{-\glueexpr\topsep + \baselineskip}]
    \item Prove that...
    \item Next ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

Another possibility would be to define your own enumerate-like list, like this:

```
\newlist{enumexp}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumexp,1]{$(a)$, leftmargin=3.2em, before=\vspace*{-\glueexpr\topsep + \baselineskip}}
```

and code in the document body:

```
\eq. =\begin{enumexp}
\item ...
.........
\end{enumpexp}
```

Comment: @Circumscribe: I'm not very familiar with glue expressions, so I didn't even think of it. Thanks for the tip! I've changed the code accordingly.

Comment: for me your last command does´t work. When I was trying use it the following message appeared: File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.

Comment: Which last command? `before= ...` in the optional arguments of enumerate? Maybe you've forgotten a closing delimiter. Could you post a minimal code reproducing the prob!em?

Comment: Bernard the first command was:

Comment: @Moura: Was what?

Comment: Bernard I don´t know what is the problem, but only the first command works for me:
\newcommand{\BegEnumExp}{\begin{enumerate}[$(a)$, leftmargin=3.2em, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep + \baselineskip}]}

\newcommand{\BegEnumExp2}{\begin{enumerate}[$(a)$, leftmargin=3.2em, before=\vspace*{-\glueexpr\topsep + \baselineskip}]}

Comment: @Moura: The error comes from using a number in the command name. If you call it `\BegEnumExpii`, it works. However I suggest defining a new enumerate-like list. Please see the edit in my answer

Comment: I really suggest using an environment: that's cleaner coding, and it's easier to debug in case of a problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new list, say `eq`, with the `resume` option for doing this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}%{\article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newlist{eq}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[eq]{resume,label={\arabic*.}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{eq}\item 
    \begin{enumerate}[$(a)$]
    \item Prove that...
    \item Next ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{eq}

\begin{eq}\item 
    \begin{enumerate}[$(a)$]
    \item Prove that...
    \item Next ...
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{eq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer! We can also put the two `enumerate` lists within the same `eq` list.

Comment: I agree with the indication given in the previous comment.

Comment: @AboAmmar is it possible to use the \noindent command together? Thaks for your beautiful answer

Comment: Yes, just add `leftmargin=*` to the options in `\setlist[eq]{resume, label={\arabic*.}, leftmargin=*}`.